# How do you specify Actionscript version in SWFC?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2, swf-compiler

I know [SWFC](http://www.swftools.org/swfc/swfc.html) supports both ActionScript 2.0 and ActionScript 3.0. But how do I specify which version a specific file is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the swfc [version statement](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/SWF_Commands):

```
.flash filename="box.swf"
  .version 7
.end
```

**References**

- [swftools : Xenial (16.04) : Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/swftools)
- [Warblefly/MultimediaTools-mingw-w64: Scripts and patches to compile many multimedia utilities, including FFmpeg, with mingw-w64 for 64-bit Windows](https://github.com/Warblefly/MultimediaTools-mingw-w64)

Comment: Thank you very much. That reference is really helpful.